# Tap should skip one of the field in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Inside a div i have a input field and link , and next to that i have another input field
so by default on pressing tab from input field1 focus goes to link . but i want to skip link from being focused on pressing tab, i,e from input field one if i press tab focus should be in input field2.

is there any html way of doing in. i don't want javaScipt/jQuery

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Tab demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
          <input type="text" name ="name1" value ="">
          <div>
             <a href="#edit-seals">Add name</a>
        </div> 
         <input type="text" name ="name2" value ="">
      </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

reference [Link here](http://jsbin.com/kinegami/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve it, using tabindex="-1". [W3C HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tab demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name ="name1" value ="">
            <div>
                <a href="#edit-seals" tabindex="-1">Add name</a>
            </div> 
            <input type="text" name ="name2" value ="">
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding attribute

> tabindex

```
<input type="text" name ="name1" value =""  tabindex="1"  >
<input type="text" name ="name2" value =""  tabindex="2" >
```

If this will work You can even manipulate in html order of tab jumping between inputs :)

[Example here :)](http://jsfiddle.net/48ej8/1/)